# Use variable instead of schema for selecting SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use variables instead of schema name but I don't want to go with `sp_executesql`

```
set schema = 'PUBLIC'
select * from identifier(schema).MYTABLE_NAME;
```

It's not working tried with `$`, `@`, table binding but didn't get the result. Please let me know how to use parameter value with hardcoded table name

Answer (score 2):

You can set a complete path using DB.SCHEMA.TABLE or SCHEMA.TABLE this way:

```
set TABLE_NAME = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.NATION';
select * from identifier($TABLE_NAME);
```

As far as I know you cannot concatenate the DB.SCHEMA or SCHEMA and the TABLE inside the `identifier` function. If you want to concatenate them programmatically, you can do something like this:

```
set SCHEMA_NAME = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1';
set TABLE_NAME = $SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || 'NATION';
select * from identifier($TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: Yeah, but i dont wanna keep it this way. i want my table name in select statement and the schema should be parameterized. if not identifier then any other way t do it ? using $,@ or any other ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If two part name is not hard requirement then [USE SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-schema) should suffice:

> Specifying a database and schema for a user session enables using unqualified object names in SQL statements and queries.

```
USE DATABASE <db_name>;
USE SCHEMA PUBLIC;

SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE_NAME;
```